# how to fetch DictionaryEntry object from Hashtable?

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashtable

I know the value of key for my Hashtable,
from key how can I obtain the object of DictinaryEntry.

I don't want to Iterate over Hashtable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `DictionaryEntry` is the type returned when you iterate a `Hashtable`, it's not really true that a `Hashtable` 'contains' `DictionaryEntry`s. `DictionaryEntry` is a value type and so doesn't have an *identity*. If you want 'a' `DictionaryEntry` containing a given key and the matching value, you can make one yourself:

```
DictionaryEntry de = new DictionaryEntry(key, myHashtable[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding your question correctly, but couldn't you just use this?

```
myHashtable[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Dictionary instead of Hashtable as it is a typed Hashtable.
For data retreivale

```
         if(myHahtable.ContainsKey(key))
            object value = myHahtable[key];
```

Comment: I've bind Hashtable with a ComboBox using BindingSource !